# Opening up a static url when using Passenger WSGI with Django?

Tags: apache, django, dreamhost

I'm currently developing a site hosted on dreamhost, using django, which is served up through passenge wsgi.

Right now, all requests are being passed to the django app. I'd like to be able to serve static content directly through apache, rather than having it go through the app. Is there a way to get passenger to realise that urls with a certain prefix are special, and should just go through to apache?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I don't need to do anything special, but there is a slight twist with the urls: static content in /public/ (e.g. <mydomain>/public/foo/index.html) is served from a url missing the /public, so the example would be served as http://<mydomain>/foo/index.html.

Obviously, trouble will ensue if static directories and django urls clash.